# What is wrong with my useEffect()? It return empty object

Tags: reactjs, axios, use-effect, use-state

I'm trying to fetch data from my server, I've tested the data fetching using Postman, everything is fine. I also double checked whether my API path was wrong, also not the issue.

I changed `useEffect` to `useLayoutEffect`, also no luck. I created a separate function outside the useEffect hook, also not working. I created console.log("I was here") on every single line, where each log was successfully printed inside the fetchProduct function.

Now I'm so stuck. I suspect the effects finish before the promise returns. Thank you in advance.

ProductDetail component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import EcommerceLayoutsTypeFourteenth from "../layouts/Ecommerce/EcommerceLayoutsTypeFourteenth/EcommerceLayoutsTypeFourteenth"
import EcommerceLayoutsTypeSecond from "../layouts/Ecommerce/EcommerceLayoutsTypeSecond/EcommerceLayoutsTypeSecond"
import axios from "axios"

const ProductDetail = ({ match, products }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
      setProduct(response.data)
    }
    fetchProduct()
  }, [match])

  return (
    <>
      <EcommerceLayoutsTypeSecond product={product} />
      <EcommerceLayoutsTypeFourteenth products={products} />
    </>
  )
}

export default ProductDetail
```

This is my App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom"
import Container from "reactstrap/lib/Container"
import FootersLayoutsTypeEighth from "./layouts/FootersLayouts/FootersLayoutsTypeEighth/FootersLayoutsTypeEighth"
import Header from "./layouts/HeaderLayouts/Header.js"
import HomeScreen from "./screens/HomeScreen"
import ProductDetail from "./screens/ProductDetail"
import axios from "axios"

const App = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProducts = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get("/api/products/")
      setProducts(response.data)
    }
    fetchProducts()
  }, [])

  return (
    <Router>
      <Container>
        <Header dark={false} />
      </Container>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          exact
          path="/"
          render={(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} products={products} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/products/:id"
          render={(props) => <ProductDetail {...props} products={products} />}
        />
      </Switch>
      <FootersLayoutsTypeEighth />
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Try wrapping it up in anonymous async function https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/how-to-use-async-function-in-react-hook-useeffect-typescript-js-6204a788a435

Comment: You say it "returns an empty object", can you show the code that demonstrates this?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts product state object, my code return this product  state as empty object `const [products, setProducts] = useState([])`

Comment: @metalheadcoder can you share what the API response looks like?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts https://ibb.co/GVv9wCm

Comment: @metalheadcoder I don't mean a screenshot of some console, I mean what the API response is _supposed_ to look like according to the tests you did on Postman. Please [edit] your question and use a code block instead of uploading a picture.

Comment: okay im sorry, here what i do in postman, GET by id `http://localhost:5000/api/products/1` response json `{
    "_id": 1,
    "title": "GP Base Coat",
    "description": "Inspired by colors and textures from art movements",
    "price": "40.00",
    "poster": "./image/flinken-product-01.png",
    "category": "gp-series",
    "link": "/products/1",
    "features": [
        "feature 1",
        "feature 2",
        "feature 3",
        "feature 4",
        "feature 5",
        "feature 6"
    ],
    "rating": 4.5
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228043/discussion-between-patrick-roberts-and-metalheadcoder).

Comment: how about console logging at your server endpoint to verify why you get an empty object. I don't see also you setting a base url config for your axios for your `http://localhost:5000`

Comment: @buzatto i make a `"proxy" : "http://localhost:5000"` inside package.json, it works fine if i fetch all product, but not single id for ProductDetail

Comment: match.params.id could be the issue. You can check devtools to check how the request looks like. And also at your server check the request that comes to validate if there is some inconsistency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the object got and array for category, it look like this..

```
    const products = [{
    _id: 1,
    title: "GP Base Coat",
    description:
      "FLINKEN® Based Coat mortar is produced according to the requirement of BS EN 998-1; incorporating standardized binder, well graded silica sand, water retention ability additve for all types of brick and block rendering.",
    price: "40.00",
    poster: "./image/flinken-product-01.png",
    category: "gp-series",
    link: "/products/1",
    features: [
      "feature 1",
      "feature 2",
      "feature 3",
      "feature 4",
      "feature 5",
      "feature 6",
    ],
    rating: 4.5,
  },...]
```

So every-time i call the `products.features[0]` the data inside my products state will become empty object.. so the solution here i just create state for features and products separately..

```
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({})
  const [feature, setFeature] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
      setFeature(data.features)
      setProduct(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [id])
```

thank you to all of you that contribute your time and effort to help me last week, i really appreciate all of you!

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap it up in anonymous async function like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/products/")
        const json = await response.json()
        setProducts(json)
    })()
}, [])
```

Also, keep in mind that whenever you're creating an "async" function, you need to resolve the promise.
So if your function is constructed like this

```
const fetchProduct = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`)
  const json = await response.json()
  return json;
}
```

You need to resolve it like this

```
fetchProduct.then((data) => // do something)
```

Or you can resolve it under anonymous async function like this

```
const data = await fetchProduct()
```

Comment: ive tried, but still return empty object, and why we need empty bracket there? i don't understand? `useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/products/")
        setProducts(response.data)
    })()
}, [])`

Comment: Are you sure you tried it correctly? Because this is how I use async functions in the `useEffect` hook and it works every time. The empty bracket in the `useEffect` hook is a dependency array, meaning that the state you put in that bracket, `useEffect` will run every time that state updates, while the empty bracket means that the `useEffect` will run only once, when component mounts.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I though that 'axios' returns JSON as default, but it turns out that it needs to resolve JSON first, just like `fetch()`

Answer (score -1):

why didnt you setProduct like this:

```
await axios.get(`/api/products/${match.params.id}`).then((res) => setProduct(res.data));
```

an async/await function return a Promise so maybe you can't get product when set product from response outside.